# Met with "Index Out of Range" when Trying to Transpose Matrix

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out how to transpose a matrix with vectors that contain an unequal amount of elements.

I'm just learning to program and I'm currently working through the Python Tutorial and I'm stuck on an example listed in "Nested List Comprehensions" here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions.

Here is a very slight variation of example shown in the Python Tutorial:

```py
matrix = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9],
]
[[row[i] for row in matrix] for i in range(3)]
```

I decided to create my own solution for the example because I wanted the code to be a bit more dynamic, which was this:

```py
matrix = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9],
]
[[row[i] for row in matrix] for i in range(len(matrix))]
```

However, shortly after coming up with my solution I noticed there was a lot of ways it could still break and tried figuring out a solution that wouldn't break under any of the following scenarios:

```py
# Scenario 1: Vectors of unequal length sizes.
matrix = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7],
    [8, 9, 10, 11]

# Scenario 2: len(vector) > len(matrix)
matrix = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7, 8]
]

# Scenario 3: len(vector) < len(matrix)
matrix = [
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4],
    [5, 6],
    [7, 8]
]
```

If anyone can come up with a solution using nested list comprehensions that would be able to handle all 3 of these scenarios, I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: How do you want the transpose of a two-dimensional array with unequal row lengths look like?

Answer (score 0):

disclaimer: all of this assumes your rows are all of the same length (as should be for a matrix).

just a minor tweak will do:

```
[[row[i] for row in matrix] for i in range(len(matrix[0]))]
```

the point is to have `i` in the range of the length of the rows of you matrix `len(matrix[0])` (i am using the first row here as it always should exist).

a more elegant way is using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
list(zip(*matrix))
```

although you will get `tuple`s as rows. if you need lists you can do:

```
[list(row) for row in zip(*matrix1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for both equal and unequal row lengths by collapsing the sparse rows to the left:

```
[[row[i] for row in matrix if i < len(row)] for i in range(max(len(r) for r in matrix))]
```

So scenario 1

```
matrix = [
[1, 2, 3, 4],
[5, 6, 7],
[8, 9, 10, 11]]
```

becomes

```
[[1, 5, 8],
[2, 6, 9],
[3, 7, 10],
[4, 11]]
```